# IConfiguration provider for Azure pipeline variables

Tags: azure-devops, .net-core-configuration

Is there an `IConfiguration` [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for Azure Devops [pipeline variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)?

I googled this for about 15 minutes but could not find anything.

We have a series of `net5.0` projects with corresponding unit and integrations tests that rely in pipeline variables as follows:

- Tests use an `IConfigurationBuilder`, including environment variables
- Variables are added to an Azure Devops Pipeline
- Modify the pipeline `yaml` to map the pipeline variables to environment variables

This is fairly straight forward. For each configuration setting that needs to be driven by a pipeline variable, we:

- Create the pipeline variable
- Modify the pipeline `yaml` to map the variable to an environment variable

  - on rare occasions, [transform the value via powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464976/vsts-release-multi-line-variable/49947273)

I'd prefer to do something like:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddEnvironmentVariables(...)
  .AddPipelineVariables(...)  // considering writing this; don't what to reinvent the wheel
```

and skip the modifications to the pipeline `yaml`.

Comment: You could try it with [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script), then you could change the value before run the build.